# The system does not store the path which I have set in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, flutter, zsh

I have placed this line in my .bash_profile.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/margrietpronk/Developer/flutter/bin"
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
~                                                                                                             
".bash_profile" 1L, 63C
```

Every time I restart my Mac, the path is not there. When I add this path manually, by the same command, then the path is known.

without adding it manually, when I put in echo $path, it shows:

```
Margrietje@iMac-van-MG ~ % echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

when I add the command manually, it says:

```
Margrietje@iMac-van-MG ~ % echo $path                                                    
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Users/margrietpronk/Developer/flutter/bin
```

Then the path is working.
How can I fix this? I thought it has to do with the name "Margrietje" before the @ ???

Comment: What shell do you use? `.bash_profile` is read only by Bash, in some conditions. And, at least for Bash, `$PATH` and `$path` are different environment variables.

Comment: Are you sure that `.bash_profile` is located in the home folder?

Comment: Thanks you all for helping. It was in the home folder and indeed there is a different between capitals and not. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged your question *bash*, but the fact that `echo $path` outputs the PATH as array, indicates that you are not using bash. My guess is that you are running Zsh, because in Zsh, `PATH` and `path` are kept in sync. You can verify this by doing a

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

and

```
echo $ZSH_VERSION
```

Of course if you do run Zsh, changing `.bash_profile` has no effect, and the changes should go into `.zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have put in both comands. The terms are new for me. I will try to edit the .zshrc.
    Margrietje@iMac-van-MG ~ % echo $BASH_VERSION

    Margrietje@iMac-van-MG ~ % echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.7.1
Margrietje@iMac-van-MG ~ %

Comment: As you see, i suspect correctly that you don't use bash. I suggest that you  remove the _bash_ tag from your question and add a _zsh_ tag instead, otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: I have added the zsh tag as you suggested. I also kept the bash tag, because I first thought the failure was in the bash_profile file. So I would have searched on that tag and not on zsh. Before your suggestion, I had never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched back to the zsh shell, as advised by @chepner
First I had to make the file .zshrc, because it wasn't there. I have edit it explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac

I have put in the path for flutter: 
    export PATH="$PATH:/Users/margrietpronk/Developer/flutter/bin"

Then I switched in the terminal to the zsh shell:
    chsh -s /bin/zsh

The path is working now. Hope this is helping somebody with the same problem as I had.